# What is the best way to ensure that primary key and foreign key never intersect?

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key

Say I have a table with a primary key `a_id` and foreign key `b_id`.

It is important that `a_id` and `b_id` never intersect, i.e. it should never be the case that there exists an `a_id = b_id`.

What would be the best way to implement this?  Could I somehow do this on the database end (mySql), or should this be ensured programmatically?  If I ensure this programmatically, is it bad practice to insert a number for a primary key (rather than have the database autoincrement it)?  I assume I would just create a routine that checks the latest primary key and simply increments it (and I would also need to ensure that the range of `a_id` never intersects the range of `b_id`).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Normally, a foreign key must match the corresponding primary key; the intersection of A and B must equal B (though there might be entries in A without a matching entry in B).  So, what do you mean by primary and foreign keys not intersecting?  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create another table that has the auto-increment field. Upon insertion of a record, it would insert into that "key table" and use the referenced values there. So if you have two globally unique keys in one table each insert would be two key inserts.  This solution would scale beyond 2 as well.

But I have to ask: Why?

Comment: Basically the idea was that each key represents some generic object id that I eventually display on a page.  I wanted the javascript identifiers to generically identify the items by the object id (which wouldn't work if a_id and b_id intersect)..I guess I could just redesign this on the front end if its too much of a hassle to do it on the db side

Comment: OK, so instead of the second unique column, why not have another column like Object_Type?  Further you could generate a GUID and use that.

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to go with the "master table" approach and just insert into this table before any other insertions and borrow its auto-incremented id. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you could implement this behavior using a `sequence` that was used to assign id's to rows in both tables.  Each table would have a trigger on `INSERT` where the id would be set from the next number in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value such that one table has only odd numbers and the other has only evens.

This is likely to be very performant, but it doesn't leave room for adding a 3rd table with yet another unique key.

I'm not 100% sure about MySQL, but with Oracle you can define a sequence, then simply use that same sequence to select all of your values from, which is probably the best option (if it is available with mysql).

Comment: This won't work if `b_id` is a parent ID and references `a_id` as its superset.

Comment: Maybe I misread the question, but I didn't see anything that says he wants b_id to be a subset of a_id. If that is the case, then you are correct.   However, this same flaw exists if they use a sequence, as suggested in some other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use a `CHECK` constraint. Unfortunately, MySQL being MySQL, it doesn't support `CHECK`.

In order to achieve the same effect in MySQL, you will need to create a `BEFORE INSERT` and a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger to make sure that both values are valid. The FK itself is in charge of making sure the relationship is valid. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON sometable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.a_id = NEW.b_id THEN
        call ERROR_SELFREFERENCING_ID();
    END IF;
END;
```

More information about MySQL TRIGGERS are available in the MySQL Manual:

> [18.3.1: Trigger Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

**EDIT:** MySQL doesn't currently support `RAISE` or `SIGNAL` in their triggers, so I have to resort to calling a non-existent procedure `ERROR_SELFREFERENCING_ID()` for it to fail. This will cause the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to fail if `a_id = b_id`, pretty much the same way if you would set an invalid `b_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier)s (UUIDs) as unique keys.

I have used this on several projects and it works well for uniqueness, although it isn't the best for index performance.